# Recurrence relation $a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

For the recurrence relation, $a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n$ with $a_0=2$ and $a_1=3$, compute the first six terms of the sequence and derive a closed form formula for this sequence.
So I'm totally lost with this question because every recurrence relation I have tried was sum of two previous terms. Any clear explanation would be greatly appreciated so that I can do this type of question in the future.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/254421/12042) is a fairly detailed solution of a very similar recurrence; it shows one standard elementary method of finding a closed form for a recurrence of this type.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I looked at the link you gave and observed your detailed answer. But Im still having hard time connecting the two since my question starts with $a_{n+2} =$. The thing that is really throwing me off is the fact that my question starts with $a_{n+2}$.

Comment: The recurrence $a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n$ for $n\ge 0$ is identical to the recurrence $a_n=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 2$ and to the recurrence $a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$: all three say exactly the same thing, that each term from $a_2$ on is $3$ times the previous term minus $2$ times the one before that.

Comment: Oh! Finally think I got it. If whenever one of these recurrence relations begin with a term $a_{n+k}$ or $a_{n-k}$, we either subtract or add the k from both sides, correct?

Comment: You can always shift the indices, provided that you shift them all by the same amount. For instance, $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}$ is the same as $a_{n+1}=2a_n+3a_{n-2}$ (all shifted up by $1$), $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+3a_{n-1}$ (all shifted up by $2$), $a_{n+3}=2a_{n+2}+a_n$ (all shifted up by $3$), or even $a_{n+5}=2a_{n+4}+3a_{n+2}$ (all shifted up by $5$). You can also shift down: $a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}+3a_{n-4}$.

Comment: So for $a_{n+5}=2a_{n+4}+3a_{n+2}$ would be same as $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-3}$, correct? If so, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct: substituting $n=10$, say, into the first version tells you that $a_{15}=2a_{14}+3a_{12}$, which is exactly what you learn by substituting $n=15$ into the second version. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the first six terms is well defined.  You are given $a_0=2, a_1=3$ and $a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n$.  If you substitute $n=2$ you get $a_{2}=3a_{1}-2a_0=3\cdot 3 -2 \cdot 2=5$ and you can keep going.  A spreadsheet with copy down will make it easy to get the next terms.

The general solution is like your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361379/recurrence-relations-for-c-1-and-c-2).  In this case, if the solution is $a_n=cr^n$, you finde $cr^2=3cr-2c$ or $r^2-3r+2=0$ with solutions $r=1$ and $r=2$.  Then we have $a_n=c_1n+c_2n^2$ and the initial conditions let you find $c_1,c_2$

Answer (score 0):

With the first two terms are given to you ($a_0=2$ and $a_1=3$), the only  coefficients left to find are $a_i$ for $i=2,3,4,5,6$.

Start with $a_2$,

$a_2 = 3a_1 - 2a_0 = 3\cdot3-2\cdot2= 9 -4=5$

then $a_3 = 3a_2 - 2a_1 = 3 \cdot 5 - 2 \cdot 3 = 15-6 = 9$

and so forth. The terms you solve previously carry over to the next iteration, and therefore, solving from the bottom up will work. Let us re-examine $a_3$ in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$:

$a_3 = 3a_2 - 2a_1 = 3(3a_1 - 2a_0)-2a_1 = 7a_1-6a_0= 21-12 =9$

which is the same as the simple method of carrying answers from iteration to iteration.

**EDIT:** From (http://people.uncw.edu/tompkinsj/133/recursion/homogeneous.htm),

From the website above, the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} = 3a_{n+1} -2a_{n}$ can be solved with the Distinct Roots Theorem.

Consider $a_{n+k} = t^k$, then the relation becomes $t^2-3t+2=(t-2)(t-1)=0$. The roots, denoted by $r$ and $s$, are $2$ and $1$, respectively. By the Distinct Roots Theorem, the sequence satisfies the following equation $a_{n} = C\cdot r^n+D \cdot s^n=C \cdot2^n +D$.

With the initial terms ($a_0=2$ and $a_1=3$), $C$ and $D$ can be solved for by the following equations:

$a_0 = C\cdot 2^0+D = C+D=2$

$a_1 = C\cdot 2^1+D = 2C+D=3$

$(a_1-a_0) = C =1$

$\implies D = 1$

$\therefore a_n = 2^n + 1^n = 2^n + 1$

Verify with $a_3$: $a_3 = 2^3 +1 = 9$ which is the same as solving the recurrence manually.

Comment: I looked at the following link but it still does not help, at least for me, how to solve the question I asked.

Comment: Sorry for the link I posted before. It definitely was not what your question was asking. I have revised my answer with a new link that may help you with finding closed form solutions for recurrence relations.

Comment: Im a bit confused as to how you got C and D. To determine C, you do $(a_1-a_0)$ which is $(C+D)-(2C+D)$, correct?

Comment: Right! I did that to isolate the constant ($(2C+D)-(C+D)=C$). I accidentally put $D$ instead of $C$. Luckily, both $C$ and $D$ are 1.

Comment: Now to solve for D, would it be $D = 2 - C$ or $D = 2 - 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Use Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) methods. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply your recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n  \ge 0$ to get:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} = 3 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - 2 A(z)
$$
Solve for $A(z)$ and split into partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 2 z} + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
a_n = 2^n - 1
$$