# Recurrence relations for $a_{n+2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to figure out how to find closed form equations for recurrence relations. I can find lots of examples for solving equations such as $a_{n} = ca_{n-1} + ca_{n-2}$ and $a_{n+1} = ca_{n} + ca_{n-1}$, but I came across a problem of $a_{n+2} = ca_{n+1} + ca_{n}$. How would the typical method for finding closed form equations ([like the one described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361379/recurrence-relations-for-c-1-and-c-2)) change for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

All three equations you give are (essentially) the same. For example, put $n+2= m$ to reduce the third to the first.

Answer (score 1):

Set $b_n=a_{n+2}$ or $d_n=a_{n+1}$ and solve for $b_n$ or $d_n$